# How to conciliate / constraint types between two separated expressions

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

I'm playing with [haskell-distributed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process) (Cloud Haskell) and I cannot make use of type constraint using returning type (must be as `... -> Process ()`).

To simplify context (and give a reproducible example), let

```
-- Request / Response
data ReqRes a b = Req a | Res b deriving (Read, Show)
```

and one generic function mapping generic processes

```
compute :: (Read a, Read b, Show a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> IO ()
compute f = do
    req <- readLn
    case req of
      Res _ -> error "Req expected"
      Req a -> print $ Res $ f a
```

this cannot compile since `req <- readLn` and `Res $ f a` cannot deduce `b` type and `a` types respectively.

My solution is use a variant of `const` to *"link / constraint"* both expressions:

```
linkType :: a -> a -> a
linkType = flip const

compute' :: (Read a, Read b, Show a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> IO ()
compute' f = do
    req <-readLn
    case req of
      Res _ -> error "Req expected"
      Req a -> print $ linkType req $ Res $ f a
```

now compile and works fine

```
> compute' (2 *)
Req 12
Res 24

> compute' (show :: Int -> String)
Req 12
Res "12"
```

but I wish to know the correct way to do this kind of things.

Thank you!

Comment: I would say your way is the correct way! The only thing is that `linkType` is defined in the base library - it is called `asTypeOf` - so you should use that. The modern GHC solution is to use ScopedTypeVariables - allowing you to refer to the type variables in the type signature, inside the definition of the function.

Comment: Why do you have one type that can represent *either* requests *or* responses? In what situation will you want to have your hands on something at runtime that may be one or the other, but is unclear which at compile time? Another way to say this is that your example is too simplified, because `compute :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> IO (); compute f = readLn >>= print . f` works just fine without needing the weird `ReqRes` type or the partial pattern match.

Comment: @DanielWagner as I know, both request and response must to be encoded into the same message data type (that is the question). Your example (but is correct) erase the relevant code and equate (in essence) `compute ~ f`. My real intention is distribute some computation `f` over the network easilly. Here is my work in progress https://gist.github.com/josejuan/1f65fb3306c5b165214a Thank you!

Comment: @josejuan "both request and response must to be encoded into the same message data type" <- this sounds a bit dodgy to me. I encourage you to open a fresh question specifically about Cloud Haskell to verify this, as "there can be only one global message type" is both antimodular and quite stylistically different from most Haskell library design principles.

Comment: @DanielWagner (too long to reply) I didn't say "only one global". Since data is serialized you can separate Request and Response, obviously (with disadvantages). Any way I follow the simple Simon Marlow's schema http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/slides/cadarache2012/6%20-%20cloud%20haskell.pdf#page=11&zoom=auto,-227,536 Of course thank you for your interest!