# Type inference for MultiParamTypeClasses?

Tags: haskell

I was writing some code that I thought was obviously correct but it seems that GHC doesn't think so:

```
class Convert a b where
    convert :: a -> b
class (Convert a b, Convert b c) => F a b c where 
    f  :: a -> c
    f = f2 . f1 
      where f2 = convert :: b -> c
            f1 = convert :: a -> b
```

Code above gives such error message, So I wonder what difficulty did GHC met when trying to deduce the proper type, or do I have to provide GHC more type infomation?

```
Main.hs:53:18:
    Could not deduce (Convert b2 c2) ac)
      bound by the class declaration for ‘F’ at Main.hs:(50,1)-(54,34)
    Possible fix:
      add (Convert b2 c2) to the context of
        an expression type signature: b2 -> c2
    In the expression: convert :: b -> c
    In an equation for ‘f2’: f2 = convert :: b ->    where
              f2 = convert :: b -> c
              f1 = convert :: a -> b

Main.hs:54:18:
    Could not deduce (Convert a2 b2) arising from a use of ‘convert’
    from the context (F a b c)
      bound by  Possible fix:
      add (Convert a2 b2) to the context of
        an expression type signature: a2 -> b2
    In the expression: convert :: a -> b
    In an equation for ‘f1’: f1 = convert :: a -> b
    In an equation for ‘f’:
        f = f2 . f1
          where
              f2 = convert :: b -> c
              f1 = convert :: a -> b
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `f` doesn't contain any `b`. Therefore, there is no way to specify what `b` is supposed to be! But you need that info; for an extreme example consider converting<sup>†</sup> `Double` -> `Int` -> `Double` (which would clearly have to round the result) vs. the trivial conversion `Double` -> `Double` -> `Double`, which supposedly wouldn't change anything.
There are two ways to get around this:

1. Make `b` *functionally dependent* on either `a` or `c` (these *can* be read from the signature). You can either do this right in `Convert`

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

   class Convert a b | a -> b where
     convert :: a -> b
   class (Convert a b, Convert b c) => F a b c where 
     f  :: a -> c
     f = convert . convert
   ```

   ...however, this means that every type can only be converted to exactly one other type! For any `a`, you can only specify one instance `Convert a b`, otherwise it's no functional dependency. — Or, you can do it in `F`

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

   class Convert a b where
     convert :: a -> b
   class (Convert a b, Convert b c) => F a b c | a c -> b where 
     f  :: a -> c
     f = f'
      where f' :: ∀ a b c . F a b c => a -> c
            f' = f2 . f1
             where f1 = convert :: a -> b
                   f2 = convert :: b -> c
   ```

   <del>Yeah, this something quite annoying: type variables like `a` in `class (Convert a b, Convert b c) => F a b c` don't have a scope. You can bring a `b` type variable explicitly in scope with the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, but this requires an explicit-universally qualified signature.</del><sup>←Turns out this is not necessary here, see josejuan's answer.</sup>
   This approach makes more sense, because you can still have multi-way conversion.
2. Explicitly specify `b` at the *call site*. This can be done if you give `f` a *tagged* type signature:

   ```
   import Data.Tagged

   class Convert a b where
     convert :: a -> b
   class (Convert a b, Convert b c) => F a b c where 
     f  :: Tagged b (a -> c)
     f = f'
      where f' :: ∀ a b c . F a b c => Tagged b (a -> c)
            f' = Tagged (f2 . f1)
             where f1 = convert :: a -> b
                   f2 = convert :: b -> c
   ```

   The advantage over a fundep on `f` is that you can now specify *any* `instance F a b c` you like. With the fundep, for any `a` and `c` you can only choose one `b`. On the flip side, it's now more cumbersome to call `f` (see [the `Tagged` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.3/docs/Data-Tagged.html)), though this [will become nicer in the future](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ExplicitTypeApplication).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>If you don't actually need to add a `Convert Double Int` instance then I would suggest you don't do it.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Both `f1` and `f2` use `b` but this is free (not constrained on `f`). How can `ghci` determine `b`?

You can use `ScopedTypeVariables` to *"link"* the `b` type on `f1` and `f2` with the `b` on `class` constraint

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
class Convert a b where
    convert :: a →  b
class (Convert a b, Convert b c) ⇒  F a b c | a c → b where -- #1
    f  :: a →  c
    f = f2 . f1
      where f2 = convert :: ∀ b . F a b c ⇒ b →  c -- #2
            f1 = convert :: ∀ b . F a b c ⇒ a →  b -- #3

instance Convert Int String where
  convert = show
instance Convert String Double where
  convert = read
instance F Int String Double where
```

now

```
> f (34 :: Int) :: Double
34.0
```

Without `ScopedTypeVariables` the `b` type **names** on #1, #2 and #3 are all differents (althoug #2 and #3 are inferred the same by `f2 . f1`). With `ScopedTypeVariables` all (#1, #2 and #3) are the same type.

On the other hand, `FunctionalDependencies` is needed to select `b` from two given `a` and `c` since `f` have not information about it.

Finally, take a look to @leftaroundabout response, if you can, looks better specify the `b` type on `f` constraint using phantom types.

(related question [How to conciliate / constraint types between two separated expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927439/how-to-conciliate-constraint-types-between-two-separated-expressions))

Comment: Interesting! Why don't you need to explicitly bring `b` in scope for `f` here?

Comment: @leftaroundabout `FlexibleInstances` select the intermediate instance (`String` in this case)

Comment: Why is the "forall" needed here? I tried removing it in your source code and it still works. I haven't used "forall" before...

Comment: Usually, when you write a function with `ScopedTypeVariables` use `forall` to set scoped type variables to whole body (see  https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables). In this case, the body is only one expression.